# Clicking on an object in the Selection Pane does not select the object

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I have a few pictures in my document that are hard to see by eye, and whose formatting I'd like to change, or even to remove the pictures. However, clicking on the various objects in the selection pane (below) does not do anything. I am not taken to the part of the document where the object is, and the cursor does not move to it. Only if the object is in the current screen will it be selected, but otherwise the selection pane is no use finding out *where* it is. I also cannot get a right-click menu from the objects.

[image]

The only thing I can do is delete the object, and each time browse through the doc hoping it will be obvious what has disappeared.

It's amazing that such a glaring bug exists in Word 2021. Any way to work around it?

Comment: This is one good reason to give your objects identifiable names instead of "Picture 3".  I have made it a habit to name objects as soon as I insert them, so I can avoid exactly this confusion. - How about zooming out so you can see 16 pages on the screen. You might then see the selection handles of the selected object.

Comment: Office 2021 has many strange problems. You can give a feedback: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-do-i-give-feedback-on-microsoft-office-2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11

Comment: @teylyn I rename objects as well in my own docs, except this one belongs to someone else. Also, I realised that this inability to select objects happens with ANY document I open, so it's not related to any one doc, or to docs that have been edited on multiple machines. I think that Word 2021 is just really buggy, as Lee says :-(

Without this bug, it wouldn't have been a problem to have generically-named objects. 

What you suggest is a good workaround, however this doc is huge, so even zooming out at 10% still leaves a lot to be scrolled before the selection handle is seen.

Comment: thanks @Lee, will do